Font Rendering: Nerd Font icons render incorrectly
The following is how I set my fonts in init.el.
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "Iosevka Term Nerd Font" :height 130)
(set-face-attribute 'fixed-pitch nil :font "Iosevka Term Nerd Font")
(set-face-attribute 'variable-pitch nil :font "Iosevka Nerd Font")

The purpose of using the Nerd Font patched versions of Iosevka was to have nice icons on dirvish, since I use it as my primary file manager. However, it renders many glyphs incorrectly, or not at all. By 'incorrectly' I mean that, for example, my directories get marked with glyphs for files. HTML files get marked with glyphs for directories. Directories that serve as git repositories are marked with music notes, while PDFs are all marked with garbage can glyphs, and dotfiles are marked with glyphs of printers. Still other glyphs simply present as squares with four alphanumerics (looks hexadecimal) inside.
I have installed the nerd-icons.el package:
(use-package nerd-icons
  :custom
  (nerd-icons-font-family "Iosevka Term Nerd Font"))

And I have set the nerd-icons attribute in dirvish:
(use-package dirvish
  :init
  (dirvish-override-dired-mode)
  :config
  (setq dirvish-attributes
    '(vc-state nerd-icons subtree-state collapse git-msg file-size))
  (setq dirvish-subtree-state-style 'nerd)
  (setq delete-by-moving-to-trash t)
  (setq dirvish-path-separators (list
                                 (format "  %s " (nerd-icons-codicon "nf-cod-home"))
                                 (format "  %s " (nerd-icons-codicon "nf-cod-root_folder"))
                                 (format " %s " (nerd-icons-faicon "nf-fa-angle_right")))))

This seems to encompass the recommended configuration on the nerd-icons Github page, as well as what I have seen others describe as sufficient for fixing their own issues with nerd fonts. As a final note, some of the glyphs render with odd alignment issues, where they partially overlap with the next character, making it harder to read. What am I missing?

This looks like three different questions all at once. You should split them up into separate posts so that they can each get appropriate answers.
